# Single query instead of multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hello I am stuck in a SQL statement situation. Can anyone help me with the statement:

**Table 1**.

```
Customers
customer_id | customer_name | custom_url | customer_desc
```

**Table 2.**

```
Categories
category_id | customer_id | category_name
```

`select customer_id where category_name="Realtor";`

gives me a list of customer ids. Now I use them to find all their names, desc and url from the customers table.

I need to do this in a single query and process the customer details to display on the UX. I am really stuck how to do this.

Here is what i have (which I know is wrong)

```
select * from customers where customer_id = Loop (select customer_id from categories where category_name="Realtor");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your query to a `JOIN` query like

```
select c.* 
from customers c
join categories ca on c.customer_id = ca.customer_id
where ca.category_name='Realtor';
```

Comment: Thank you so much rahul!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using `IN` or `ANY` or `EXISTS`:

```
select *
from customers
where customer_id = ANY (select customer_id
                         from categories
                         where category_name = 'Realtor'
                        );
```

Or:

```
select *
from customers
where customer_id IN (select customer_id
                      from categories
                      where category_name = 'Realtor'
                     );
```